# Python Pandas groupby multiple counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
   id          email     domain          created_at   company
0  1   son@mail.com    old.com 2017-01-21 18:19:00  company_a
1  2   boy@mail.com    new.com 2017-01-22 01:19:00  company_b
2  3  girl@mail.com  nadda.com 2017-01-22 01:19:00  no_company
```

I need summarize the data by Year, Month and if the company has a value that doesn't match "no_company":

Desired output:

```
year        month       company      count                                  
2017        1           has_company    2
                        no_company     1
```

The following works great but gives me the count for each value in the company column;

```
new_df = test_df['created_at'].groupby([test_df.created_at.dt.year, test_df.created_at.dt.month, test_df.company]).agg('count')
print(new_df)
```

result:

```
year        month       company                                       
2017        1           company_a      1
                        company_b      1
                        no_company     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map a new series for `has_company`/`no_company` then `groupby`:

```
c = df.company.map(lambda x: x if x == 'no_company' else 'has_company')
y = df.created_at.dt.year.rename('year')
m = df.created_at.dt.month.rename('month')

df.groupby([y, m, c]).size()

year  month  company    
2017  1      has_company    2
             no_company     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you!